# Sound script for local players in ROBLOX

Tags: lua, roblox

I need a script that changes sound for each player whenever that player touches a part. Sound should be player specific.
 I want the script to work on local player so that whenever he touches a part sound should be played at his machine not other players. I have place where there is unique sound for every stage. Like my place has about 15 sounds, so they should be played when player touches

stage1 -> play sound for stage1
stage2-> stop sound of stage1, play sound for stage2

so on...

Answer (score 0):

Make a script that puts the sound in game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui

Comment: I tried that but its not working as expected.
Here is my script.

Comment: local leaderstats = game.Players.LocalPlayer:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
if leaderstats then
if leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Level") then
while wait(0) do
local sounds = game.Workspace.SoundModel:GetChildren()
for x = 1, #sounds do
if x == leaderstats.Level.Value then
local sound = sounds[x]
if not leaderstats.Parent.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild(sound) then
for _,sons in pairs(game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:GetChildren())do
if sons.ClassName == "Sound" then
sons:Destroy() endend local clone = sound:Clone()
clone.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui      clone:Play()
endendendendendend

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches you can take for this. One way you can do it is to place a sound inside a folder inside player.Backpack or player.PlayerGui or anywhere in the localplayer and just change the soundid before you play it.

```
    local soundids = {}
    soundids[1] = 478920872
    soundids[2] = 478920872
    soundids[3] = 478920872
    soundids[4] = 478920872
    soundids[5] = 478920872
    soundids[6] = 478920872
    soundids[7] = 478920872
    soundids[8] = 478920872
    soundids[9] = 478920872
    soundids[10] = 478920872
    soundids[11] = 478920872
    soundids[12] = 478920872
    soundids[13] = 478920872
    soundids[14] = 478920872
    soundids[15] = 478920872

    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer  --get localplayer

    local sound = player.Backpack.Sound    --get sound NOTE:the sound can be                 stored somewhere else

    local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")  -- get leaderstats

    if leaderstats and leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Level") then   -- make sure leaderstats and leaderstats.level exists

        local level = leaderstats.Level           
        local levelnum = level.Value   --record level.Value for comparison

        level.Changed:connect(function()  --if a property of level changes then run this function
            if levelnum ~= level.Value then  --make sure that the property changed was the Value property 
                levelnum = level.Value      --record the new Value
                if soundids[levelnum] ~= nil then  --make sure the soundid exists to avoid an error
                    sound.SoundId = 'rbxassetid://'..soundids[levelnum]  --change the Sound.SoundId to the levels' corresponding sound   
                    sound:Play() -- play the sound
                end
            end
        end)
    end
```